# SQL-запрос с строкой в одном столбце и со значением count(*) в другой

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

Извините за ламерство, вопрос действительно из разряда "да почему я так туплю". Имею запрос типа

```
select count(if(`Квартира` IS NOT NULL, 1, null)) as `В многоквартирных домах`,
 count(if(`Квартира` IS NULL, 1, null)) as `В частном секторе`
from (`smth` join `smth_else` on((`xxxx`.`xxxx` = `xxxx`.`xxxx`)))
 WHERE `one_more_smth` BETWEEN 24 AND 29"
```

А потом этот запрос идёт через fetch_assoc\fetch_array и данные json_encode-ятся в PHP. Проблема в том, что json_encode выдаёт мне это в одну строку (так и должно быть по запросу), а мне нужен формат типа:

В частном секторе: xxxx

В многоквартирных домах: xxxx

Это нужно для Highcharts. Не подскажете, как изменить запрос так, чтобы привести данные к нужному формату, или настроить highcharts так, чтобы он съел нынешний формат?

Comment: у хайчартсов одна из наиболее нормальных документаций из всех чартов с чем я работал, там примеров тонна.

Comment: Да, тоже удивился адекватности доков. Тут вопрос больше по MySQL, мне просто интересно, можно ли сделать такой запрос. Я бы не хотел трогать текущий сетап, а вот запросы такого вида мне ещё пригодятся. Вообще, такое возможно?

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите получить эти данные в 2 строки ? тогда сделайте `group by (case when \`Квартира\` is null then 1 else 2) end)` и такое же условие в начале запроса выведите что бы одну строку от другой можно было отличить (ну или вместо 1 и 2 прямо строки свои сделайте 'В частном секторе')

Comment: @Mike там еще сам селект надо переделать тогда, чтобы значение было в одном столбце

Comment: @teran Ну да, просто count(*) без всяких условий, думаю человек, написавший IF в count догадается :)

Comment: Спасибо, получилось в две строки, но не понял как написать свою, чтобы различить - не получается.